# Location manager return null values in Iran in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am creating an app like Uber in Iran, but my location manager will not give me the current location of the user, it will give me only null values. How can I fetch the current location of the user in Iran? As my whole app is based on current location.

I am using the Apple maps in my application, it will return the latitude and longitude when my current location is different than Iran country.

Comment: Please share the code ? What you have tried....

Comment: I think apple map is not allowed for `Iran` location. you have to use google map to fetch current location of `Iraq`.

Comment: If you want to get current location of 'Iran' then you must use Google map.

Comment: will location manager return the latitude and longitude of current location in iran ???

Comment: I expect that Apple, as an American firm, must obey US export regulations even under sufferance, and the regulations say that Iran is a country worth placing under a financial and services embargo. I suspect you will need to use a third-party service that is not hosted within the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satellite, Direction, Navigation services of Apple are not present in Iran thats why you are not getting the location coordinates.

Please check this link from Apple: http://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/

Is better you use Google maps in your app to get your location coordinates for Iran.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro  this link will be helpful to you

Comment: will location manager return the latitude and longitude of current location in iran ???